# Intersect edges in geometry nodes

Tags: modeling, vertices, geometry-nodes, edges, sverchok

Sverchok nodes have node: "Intersect Edges", which create vertex on intersetion edges (in one object), like on the picture below:[image]

Is it possible for Blender 3.1 or 3.2 to get this solution by geometry nodes? I use node group, which create even offset and i want to create vertices in all position, where the two edges intersect, like on the picture below:

[image]

Sverchook do it very well, but sverchook is destructive for my workflow, so i want to find solution in geometry nodes.

Thanks alot in advance, if something is unclear, i can provide more info or pictures.

---

## Edit

@quellenform post solution for this problem, which works if all vertices of object are on the same "Z" position. Is it posibble to achieve in geometry nodes vertices on intersect edges, when not all vertices are on the same "Z" position?

And thanks to @quellenform i was able to achieve this:[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Geometrynodes Curve Intersections](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264070/geometrynodes-curve-intersections)

Comment: @quellenform Thanks a lot for link this answer, but unfortunately solutions from this answer works only on seperate objects. I searching for nodes, which gives similiar resultat to [sverchook](https://sverchok.readthedocs.io/en/stable/nodes/modifier_change/intersect_edges.html) or [XALL from tinyCAD](https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/latest/addons/mesh/tinycad.html)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*I'm not quite clear what exactly your goal is or what you want to do with the extra vertices, so please bear with me...*

If you are only interested in the points at the intersections of the curves, then you might be happy with this simple trick:

[image]

You can of course also filter out the points at the intersections:

[image]

PS: If you need curves at the end, you can convert the mesh back to curves with the node `Mesh to Curve`.

Comment: Many thanks for this answer! It really nice solution and for 2d object is going to be fine. I only consider if is there a option to get vertices on intersect edges, when "Z" position of vertices are not the same?

Comment: @Xostyrka it gets a bit tricky in 3 dimensions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16623657/finding-the-intersection-where-multiple-3d-parametric-equations-meet?r=SearchResults