# Remove chamfers from curves in geometry nodes

Tags: bezier-curves, geometry-nodes

I have a mesh with a bunch of vertices previously sorted, from here I am able to create, with this nodetree, a series of splines.

[image]

Now I need to get rid of the remaining chamfers,like this:

[image]

I've been trying lots of methods such as finding the intersecting point between the exterior edges of the chamfer using control point handlers as shown here [intersection of edge](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/264070/geometrynodes-curve-intersections), but it only works with single values and I need to use fields as its something to be done through al the mesh.

Any ideas on how I could approach this issue?

[image]

**EDIT**
As asked in the comments I'll try to give more info to make it easier to understand the question.

On every mesh vertex there is an object instanced, the object containing the created curves is intended to be an auxiliary object from which we can sample new positions to replace on the every vertex from the original. In the following image you can see in blue what would result the new seat positions with chamfers and in yellow how it should be.

[image]

Comment: Could you please share your blend file with us so we don't have to recreate this? https://blend-exchange.com/ Also, I'm not entirely clear on how this is supposed to work with the lines further up, but I'll be happy to look into that with your file.

Comment: @quellenform there you go, I've cleaned the blend file to make it as clear a possible, also you need blender 3.3. You can see in the node tree how I've been trying to implement your solution but with no success. Let me know if you have any questions. Thanks again

Comment: I have now taken a close look at the file, and I don't think it's a good idea to work with *Geometry Nodes* here. On the one hand, the points are not exactly lined up, and on the other hand, there are some missing at the top to get reliable results. Can you possibly tell us more about what you actually want to do here? Because I think it would be better to work on the whole thing manually, instead of trying to work out a procedural solution for an unclear goal here.

Comment: ...I mean, the goal is actually clear, only the way to get there is not at all. There are simply too many questions concerning the special cases (Which of the many individual segments should be used for an intersection? How do we deal with points standing alone? What if the points are not on a line?, etc.). ...so please tell us more about your project. Thanks!

Comment: @quellenform I was trying to keep the question as simple as possible because of the complexity of the project and its requirements, which may be dificult to understand as its for our inhouse workflow. I will try to edit the question to give you some more feedback

Comment: Can you please upload the file with the stand and the mechanism that creates the individual points? ...I would have another (possibly simpler) idea.

Comment: Right now I'm unable to give you more feedback, once I get more free time I will happy share the files with you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be quite what you expected, but it is a valid answer to *"Remove chamfers from curves in geometry nodes"*:

[image]

Here I simply calculate the missing side of the triangle at selected points (always the first point of a chamfer) using the curve tangents.

...I admit I stole this trick from Pythagoras, but I'm sure he won't mind this time for once.

Here is the node tree:

[image]

[image]
<sub>*(Blender 3.2)*</sub>

---

*PS: If this technique doesn't help you, please be so kind and share your entire file with us, because I'm sure there are other (easier?) ways to achieve the desired result for your project.*