(Geometry Nodes) Merge curves at intersections into mesh
My goal is to take a collection filled with curves and merge them into 1 mesh object (without faces). I want them to be merged at intersections of given curves, I only work with 2D curves (XY spanning curves, top-down view), but 3D approach might be useful for me later on (not a requirement though).
I already have something that kind of works. My current approach is:

I'm looking for something more stable and less prone to my error in choosing correct magic constants. I attach a file where the curves are in such state that they are not merged. Also it looks like Merge by Distance iterates indices and so not all vertices that are originally some given distance away from each other get merged into one but rather it merges one by one and sometimes ends up making mess:
Expectation:

What happens:

Ideas: Was thinking about proximity node or raytrace node but didn't figure much out. Also if there was a way to fix the center point in my current approach after the merge, that would be nice too. Something like select point with more than 2 neighbors (intersection point) and move it based of directions of neighboring edges or something like that?
Thank you in advance for time and effort.


See: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/264140/60486

This does the trick with a good precision
Using a mesh boolean (must be "union" and "exact") calculates intersections automatically.
The caveat is that you need a volumetric mesh (just edges aren't enough). So we use a low res circle so the intersections are found.
The radius of the circle in my test was 0.0001 (it appears as 0 in the node, but it's 0.0001).
Now, if we merge by distance with more than 2 times the circle radius, we convert every circle back to a single vertex.
The multiplication ratio for the merge also depends on how parallel the curves are. If they're too parallel, some merge might not occur properly.


Another option is to use high resolution and brute merges.
The downside is that I can't seem to decimate the mesh or dissolve vertices after the operation. With a high resolution value, the crossings get a little displaced. With low resolution value, the result gets good precision, but the mesh gets too many vertices.


Thank you for your response. In my experience, the Mesh Boolean node took too long for bigger collections of curves and I kind of require interactability. But since I haven't specified it in my question, this is a working solution. Will mark it as one if no better solution is posted or I don't figure something out.

@Poncaada, check the new answer, it's less precise, but doesn't use faces or boolean.

@DanielMöller I think you meant to say "With a low resolution value, the crossings get a little displaced. With high resolution value, the result gets good precision, but the mesh gets too many vertices."

Well... high resolution means a low value.
