(Geometry Nodes) Avoiding Curve Self-Crossing after Shifting Curve along Normal
I have a curve object loaded in geometry nodes and I want to create N "duplicates" of that curve, all with D distance between them. One thing is important though, the curve "duplicates" can't cross itself and create a loop (shown in an image below).

My current workflow is duplicating and then adding offset (with Set Position).

I was thinking that being able to resample curve based on the curvature, so that it has more points on straighter parts of the curve and less in the turn could solve the problem, but even when I've calculated curvature based on this video: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YExiLAs5sYQ, (it's in attached blender file as "Get Angles" group), I didn't know how to use it the way I want to. Any other ideas, approaches that get me to same result are welcome. I have also tried merge by distance in past but also didn't know how to set the distance so it works the way intended.
Requirements: I would like to have the code interactive, so "Mesh Boolean" and other 'slow' nodes are off the table for me. The curve must maintain the distance D from other curve at all points (so sampling down before duplication is not so simple)
Thank you in advance.


Looks more like a contour with offset than a duplicate, a duplicate would have the same bending angle as the original... N duplicates with distance D would be simple, just move each duplicate D units in the desired direction from the previous.

I made a personal 2d offset algorithm a few days ago (not for blender, sorry, not with nodes either, and only for straight lines), and it is one of the most difficult things I've ever tried to solve (that came out as a big surprise to me). Solving a universal offset is hard. But for this specific case, you could try to use line splits at intersections and dicard the shortest lines (not a universal solver, nor fail proof) - There is something about curve intersections here: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/325598/geometry-nodes-merge-curves-at-intersections-into-mesh/325602#325602

@GordonBrinkmann yes you are right. Using the word duplicate might not have been the best choice here, since it's not a 1-1 duplicate after it's modified/shifted. Maybe there is a better word to use, like "contour". I hope it didn't make the question more complicated to understand

@DanielMöller I see. I have been stuck on this for a while now so I def feel the complexity you mentioned. Just hoped there is some clever solution for this
