How do you generate the intersections for one Line with the Fill Curve Node?
I am trying to generate the intersections for one line with the Fill Curve node. I have read the answers on Geometrynodes Curve Intersections but, I wanted to come up with an alternative way to make my intersections.
Here are the conditions I gave myself to work with besides using the Fill Curve node,

Lines may consist of 2 OR more points
Not all lines are straight lines
Multiple Intersections can be generated from multiple lines intersecting the one line
Lines may or may not be cyclic

and below are my node trees so far.

Node Group Used;

My Approach
To generate 2D intersections by the Fill Curve node, I needed all my lines to be Cyclic. Converting my lines into cyclic shapes however, generated extra lines. With extra lines came extra intersections. My issue occurred after I found some elaborate way to delete these extra intersections. I couldn't keep my node tree from deleting existing points from the line when they coincided/overlapped with my extra intersections.
If possible, I would like to incorporate the extra condition of not deleting extra intersections if, they overlap existing points. Then, I could just merge them to get rid of them.

Blender 4.2.3

https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/325598/geometry-nodes-merge-curves-at-intersections-into-mesh/325602#325602

"Not all lines are straight lines" - in Blender, all splines are internally made of straight segments. So you need to resample the curve in "evaluated" mode, and then do the intersection test in linked thread on each segment.

Hohoho! I completely overlooked the Mesh Boolean node. I've worked that node out of my methods because of how slow it is. Now that I had some time to look over this question, Daniel Möller's answer does solve my problem however it doesn't seem to work for all of my cases.

What would you guys say if I reworked this question with an extra condition of using the Fill Curve node? Would it be too unreasonable? Just to differentiate this question from https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/325598/geometry-nodes-merge-curves-at-intersections-into-mesh/325602#325602 as an alternative way to make intersections.
